# flutter - iphone - camera flip image

Tags: flutter

When I take a photo with the iphone camera plugin in my flutter app, the image is sometime received flipped.

This happens if the phone is parallel to the ground and the phone decide that the iphone should be flipped.

My app doesn't flip the UI since it set not to rotate, but the image does flipped (180 degree)

It doesn't happen if the phone is slightly tilted, how ever end-user often receive a flipped image.

This is very annoying and it doesn't happen on android.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded camera plugin `camera: ^0.7.0+2` and it solve the problem